# How to properly use #pragma omp simd?

Tags: c++, openmp, simd

I'm trying to understand whether the code below is OpenMP standard compliant. The main concern here is the `args` object that contains an `offset` field that is modified inside a loop to which `#pragma omp simd` is applied. Is this a legit use case?

```cpp
#include <cstdio>
    
struct args_t {
    int offset;
};
    
const int n = 10;
float data1[n];
float data2[n];
    
void foo(float &res, const args_t& args) {
    res = res + data2[args.offset];
}
    
int main() {
    printf("Original arrays:\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        data1[i] = (float)i / 2.0f;
        printf("%f ", data1[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        data2[i] = (float)i / 3.0f;
        printf("%f ", data2[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
    
    args_t args;
    args.offset = 0;
    
    #pragma omp simd
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        foo(data1[i], args);
        args.offset++;
    }
    
    printf("Sum of two arrays:\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        printf("%f ", data1[i]);
    printf("\n");
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This loop can easily be vectorized by the compiler: g++ 11.2 (-O3 -mavx2) produces exactly the same vectorized assembly code regardless of the OpenMP directive is used or not.

Comment: `#pragma omp simd reduction(+:args.offset)`. You probably also want an OpenMP pragma on the function... IIRC the syntax is `#pragma omp simd declare`, but TBH I don't use that part of OpenMP often so you might want to check ;)

Comment: The question is about standard compliance and not about performance.

Comment: @nemequ This is not really a reduction here: `args.offset` is read in the loop, and it is not used outside the loop. The loop is an embarrassingly parallel one and I guess `args.offset` should be mark as `linear`.

Comment: @JérômeRichard The problem is that `args.offset` cannot be used in `linear` clause and you get an error (`args` is not integer or pointer type). The solution can be to change the code and use a reference to `args.offset`, then it can be used in `linear` clause. So, I would rephrase the OP's question to "Is it necessary to use linear clause in simd directive?" The compiler can easily determine the linear behavior of a variable in a loop..

Comment: The `linear` clause may be necessary in `#pragma omp declare simd` directive and you may get incorrect result without it, but I think it can be safely removed from `#pragma omp simd ` directive.

Comment: @Laci Indeed for the `linear`. Compilers does not like that but I did not find any restriction in the specification about this point. I am wondering if this is just a current limitation of compilers (like many others). Note that if the function is not inlined, the compiler need the information. `omp declare simd` is used to do that but again the structure is a problem and I also cannot find information about such limitation for the `declare` clause. In fact GCC appear to generate some code by default but it brute-force many combination (certainly due to the lack of information).

Comment: OpenMP specification 5.2 November 2021 5.1.1 - Variables Referenced in a Construct:
For constructs other than task generating constructs, if no default clause is present, these variables reference the variables with the same names that exist in the enclosing context.

So basically the `args` object is shared by default and can be modified simultaneously.
Creating a reference to `args.offset` won't change `args`'s attribute.

Comment: Do I interpret the standard right?

Comment: You are right, but 1) compilers (at least recent clang and gcc) recognize this case and compile it correctly , 2) the `linear` clause is also a data-sharing clause, the semantics for the `private` clause apply. Note that if you use a reference in linear clause, you have to use the reference everywhere inside the simd loop (and functions called), otherwise incorrect code is generated.

Comment: But just to be clear, the compilers may recognize such cases but they are not required to do that, right? Regarding your second point, it seems that the standard also clarifies that in the 1.2.6 Data terminology section: "A variable that is part of another variable (as an array element or a structure element) cannot be made private independently of other components". Therefore you cannot change the attribute of the `offset` field without changing it for the whole structure.

Comment: "they are not required to do that, right?" They can indeed do that for simd loops (ie. just ignore `pragma simd` statements). However, I am not sure about `declare simd` as it as a side effect at link time: the function can be visible in shared libraries and more generally translation units. AFAIK, this specific point is not mentioned in the specification, but generally, all OpenMP pragma could be ignored by a compiler since the parallel code should behave "as-if" it was sequential.

Answer (score 2):

**TL;DR answer**: OpenMP specification is not specific in this respect, which means that the answer depends on the actual implementation. In practice, your code properly vectorized (at least on newest gcc/clang on x86-64 platform), but you can specify that your variable is modified inside the loop by using the `linear` clause.

**Detailed answer:**
In the [OpenMP specification](https://www.openmp.org/spec-html/5.1/openmpsu49.html#x74-750002.11.5) the execution model of the `simd` construct is quite vaguely described:

> The `simd` construct can be applied to a loop to **indicate that** the
> loop **can be** transformed into a SIMD loop...

This gives a lot of flexibility/freedom to the compiler, and also raises many questions - like yours. The last paragraph of [this document](https://info.ornl.gov/sites/publications/files/Pub69214.pdf) is much more clear:

> OpenMP provides directives to improve the capabilities of the
> compiler’s auto-vectorization pass by providing it with information
> that cannot be determined through compile-time static-analysis. This
> allows the programmer to effectively vectorize previously problematic
> sections of code and have it run efficiently on several computer
> architectures and accelerators...

This practically means that the OpenMP `simd` directives provide only information to the compiler for auto-vectorization, but how auto-vectorization is actually performed depends on the the implementation .

So, based on the above mentioned references and some tests with Compiler Explorer (gcc and clang on x86-64 platform) I always found that if you do not provide enough information for vectorization the worst case is that the loop won't be vectorized, but it will not result incorrect code.

I have also found that using `#pragma omp simd` without any additional clause or directive is practically equivalent to the use of `#pragma GCC ivdep` (or `#pragma clang loop vectorize(assume_safety)` for clang), but it is much more portable.

In the following code, the compiler generated code first checks the value of `k` to determine if it is safe to vectorize, but if `#pragma omp simd` is added this check is omitted:

```
void vec_dep(int *a, int k, int c, int m) {
  for (int i = 0; i < m; i++)
    a[i] = a[i + k] * c; 
}
```

Consider the following example:

```
int foo(int*  A){
    int sum=0;    
    #pragma omp simd reduction(+:sum)
    for(int i=0;i<1024;++i) 
        sum+=A[i];
    return sum;
}
```

In this example `#pragma omp simd reduction(+:sum)` is the absolutely correct form, but using `#pragma omp simd` or `#pragma GCC ivdep` or not using anything at all gives similar (correctly vectorized) code. Note that this is not the case if `#pragma omp parallel for reduction(+:sum)` is used, in this case reduction is absolutely necessary to avoid race condition. (Well, this raises the obvious question why the compiler does not give a warning in such a case.)

Similarly it is not necessary to use `linear` clause (the compiler can find this linear dependence):

```
#pragma omp simd linear(b:1)
 for (int i=0;i<N;++i) array[i]=b++;
```

Note that, however, if `#pragma omp parallel for simd linear(b)` is used the `linear(b)` cannot be omitted otherwise the result will be incorrect, because the OpenMP calculates the initial `b` value for each thread using this linear relationship.

So, to answer your question, your code will compile to properly vectorized code (at least on compilers I have tested), even though the linear relationship is not specified. To specify this linear relationship you have to use the `linear` clause. The first idea to use `#pragma omp simd linear(args.offset)`, but it can't compile becasue the following error: `linear clause applied to non-integral non-pointer variable with 'args_t' type`. The workaround is to use a reference to `args.offset` and change the function `foo` accordingly:

```
void foo(float &res, const int& offset) {
    res = res + data2[offset];
}
...
int& p=args.offset;
    
    #pragma omp simd linear(p)
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        foo(data1[i], p);
        p++;
    }
```